# Can I pass a parameter to a Magnitude scoring function in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I can see from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index#bkmk_indexref) that I can use `referencePointParameter` and `tagsParameter` to pass parameters into the disance and tags scoring functions respectively.

I'd like to do the same with the `magnitude` scoring function, but can't see from the documentation how to do this (or if it's even possible).

For example, if a product was £100, I'd like to get similar products with a similar price. I think I could do this with 2 magnitude functions (e.g. boost from £80 to £100, and again from £120 to £100 will boost products closest to the £100 price of the original product).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do magnitude boosting based on relative values of a field across documents. This feature is intended for situations where you statically know the ranges that you want to boost (for example, when boosting based on a rating field with a fixed scale).